# Is there a way to receive second calculated type in overload method in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to receive second calculated type in overload method in typescript

```
  type V1 = 'v1';
  type V2 = 'v2';
  type Versions = V1 | V2;

  async analyze(test: 'v1', data: number): Promise<void>;
  async analyze(test: 'v2', data: string): Promise<void>;
  async analyze(test: Versions, data: string | number): Promise<void> {
    switch (test) {
      case 'v1':
        return this.checkNumber(data); // data is number
      case 'v2':
        return this.checkString(data); // data is string
    }
  }

  async checkString(data: string): Promise<void> {
    console.log(data);
  }

  async checkNumber(data: number): Promise<void> {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

The only acceptable way I found for now is adding conditional typing to force type it inside switch:

```
type Data<Type> = Type extends V1 ? number : string;

async analyze(test: 'v1', data: number): Promise<void>;
async analyze(test: 'v2', data: string): Promise<void>;
async analyze(test: Versions, data: Data<typeof test>): Promise<void> {
  switch (test) {
    case 'v1':
      return this.checkNumber(data as Data<typeof test>); // data is number
    case 'v2':
      return this.checkString(data as Data<typeof test>); // data is string
  }
}
```

But are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your method's return type doesn't depend on the type of the inputs (it's `Promise<void>` no matter what), then instead of explicitly using [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), you can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types as a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and [destructure it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) into the `test` and `data` parameters.  Uh, that's a lot of words; here, just look:

```
async analyze(
    ...[test, data]: [test: 'v1', data: number] | [test: 'v2', data: string]
): Promise<void> {
    switch (test) {
        case 'v1':
            return this.checkNumber(data);
        case 'v2':
            return this.checkString(data);
    }
}
```

The `test` and `data` on the left of the colon are destructured parameter names, while those on the right are [tuple labels](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements).  The `test` parameter will either be of type `'v1'` or of type `'v2`, and the `data` parameter will either be of type `number` or of type `string`.  But the compiler understands that `'v1'` for `test` implies `number` for `data`, while `'v2'` for `test` implies `string` for `data`, and so the rest of your implementation succeeds without error.

Functions taking unions of rest tuples look mostly like overloads from the caller's side, so things aren't that different for callers:

```
async calling() {
    // IntelliSense shows 2 overloads:
    // 1/2 analyze(test: "v1", data: number): Promise<void>
    // 2/2 analyze(test: "v2", data: string): Promise<void>

    this.analyze("v2", ""); // okay
    this.analyze("v1", ""); // error
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAagjFAvFA5ANzig3AWAFCiSwBMSqax2+h0MEATgM4CWA9gHaNnxQA+JuPPgDGAGwCGjLgDFWrKAG98+KKqiSQ7YevbjRIAF4QAFCrXmAdFYDawCI2AAaKABNxwcQF0AXFFv3gX3RMZzcPX3YAVwBbACMGTz4-OwcgihRQ93FfB3pmdgBzTzNVAEpfAAV6VmjmRggAHjRWZhcAPkUS8yhGAHdmYGEACyhjFOBSzrxumahhSWhglG8u2e76CGBI+nYoYCG6i2GIYQBrADkY+PpjMPFSwTXzefryShXpp5mNrZ29g8YRyGJ1OAGVgHlCrcsg9VmoAL5dRFCT6qDRaObAs7gyEFaHhHoQ-IFcpQKo1OqNZqtDpKVHdYQcRisUQQCyiVh4u6w+nIrro7THM6XOIMfHZKBRUX0Unk2r1JotdpTNaMzgstkcrkwx4I5T0gVzPSiYnGSZ0tYAektUAAkuw7KITfVOBA4aprVA4JbSOJdPojGMAr4AEQYEOZAlS66y6ryqlKtruqCe4g+nR6QwmcahigR1xZHJEwqxikK6ntfVrfaHP2ZwNh4j5kMhh4pm2sU7iEDJmuAusBkxhuDN1tYdtQBjVehI-XwoA)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to "mix" types but if you absolutely have to you can use datatype "any"

```
async someMethod(arg1: any) : Promise<void> {
...
}
```